# Special characters in countVectorizer Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Consider this runnable example:

```
#coding: utf-8
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
corpus = ['öåa hej ho' 'åter aba na', 'äs äp äl']
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
l =  vectorizer.get_feature_names()

for u in l:
        print u
```

The output will be

```
aba
hej
ho
na
ter
```

Why is the åäö removed? Note that the vectorizer strip_accents=None is default. I would be really grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which version of scikit-learn are you using?

Comment: I used the sudo apt-get to download the sklearn. What is your error message?

Comment: No error message, it works just fine. Again, what's the version? `sklearn.__version__`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an intentional way to reduce the dimensionality while making the vectorizer tolerant to inputs where the authors are not always consistent with the use of accentuated chars.

If you want to disable that feature, just pass `strip_accents=None` to `CountVectorizer` as explained in the [documentation of this class](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> CountVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii').build_analyzer()(u'\xe9t\xe9')
[u'ete']
>>> CountVectorizer(strip_accents=False).build_analyzer()(u'\xe9t\xe9')
[u'\xe9t\xe9']
>>> CountVectorizer(strip_accents=None).build_analyzer()(u'\xe9t\xe9')
[u'\xe9t\xe9']
```

Comment: I see! I just thought that accents was like the thing over é and á, but not included åäö. Thanks

Comment: I could have named this parameter `strip_diacritics` which would have been more exact but then most users would understand even less :)

Comment: If work for me: let me edit my answer with a demo on the current mast.

Comment: I meant: "It works for me: let me edit my answer with a demo on the current master branch of scikit-learn."